# How can I use terminal to copy and rename files from multiple folders?

Tags: shell, unix, cp

I have a folder called "week1", and in that folder there are about ten other folders that all contain multiple files, including one called "submit.pdf". I would like to be able to copy all of the "submit.pdf" files into one folder, ideally using Terminal to expedite the process. I've tried `cp week1/*/submit.pdf week1/` as well as `cp week1/*/*.pdf week1/`, but it had only been ending up copying one file. I just realized that it has been writing over each file every time which is why I'm stuck with one...is there anyway I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: is *submit.pdf* the name of a folder? (By the way, it looks like you're using BASH or another shell to do this, not Terminal. Terminal is (presumably) a Mac OS X application.)

Comment: submit.pdf is the name of the file I'd like to copy. Also, I'm using the Terminal application but it says `bash` on the title bar, so that must be the shell. Although I don't really know what that means.

Comment: Terminal lets you "get at" text utilities. The shell you're running is `bash`, the Bourne Again SHell, which is the Gnu version of the Bourne Shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't indicate your OS, but if you're using Gnu `cp`, you can use `cp week1/*/submit.pdf --backup=t week/` to have it (arbitrarily) number files that already exist; but, that won't give you any real way to identify which-is-which.

You could, perhaps, do something like this:

```
 for file in week1/*/submit.pdf; do cp "$file" "${file//\//-}"; done
```

… which will produce files named something like "week1-subdir-submit.pdf"

For what it's worth, the `"${var/s/r}"` notation means to take *var*, but before inserting its value, search for *s* (`\/`, meaning `/`, escaped because of the other special `/` in that expression), and replace it with *r* (`-`), to make the unique filenames.

**Edit**: There's actually *one more* `/` in there, to make it match multiple times, making the syntax:

```
             "${ var           /        /                 \/  /      -    }"
                 take "var"    replace  every instance of /   with   -
```

Comment: I'm using Terminal (bash shell) on Mac OS 10.6.8. I guess that means I'm not using Gnu `cp` because I get `cp: --backup=t: No such file or directory`.

But the line of code almost seems to work except I get the following error: `cp: week1-subdir/submit.pdf: No such file or directory` for each file/subdirectory. If I change the last part of your code to `"${file/\///}"` (thinking that this would fix the problem of finding the directory), I get `cp: week1/subdir/submit.pdf and week1/subdir/submit.pdf are identical (not copied).` for each file/subdirectory.

Comment: I hadn't accounted for multiple `/` in the filename, and had a spurious extra ` character in the line, sorry … I've edited the answer and added a little bit of explanation

Answer (score 1):

`find` to the rescue!  Rule of thumb: If you can list the files you want with `find`, you can copy them.  So try first this:

```
$ cd your_folder
$ find . -type f -iname 'submit.pdf'
```

Some notes:

- `find .` means "start finding from the current directory"
- `-type -f` means "only find regular files" (i.e., not directories)
- `-iname 'submit.pdf'` "... with case-insensitive name 'submit.dpf'".  You don't need to use `'quotation'`, but if you want to search using wildcards, you need to.  E.g.:

  ```
   ~ foo$ find /usr/lib -iname '*.So*'
   /usr/lib/pam/pam_deny.so.2
   /usr/lib/pam/pam_env.so.2
   /usr/lib/pam/pam_group.so.2
   ...
  ```

If you want to search case-sensitive, just use `-name` instead of `-iname`.

When this works, you can copy each file by using the `-exec` command.  `exec` works by letting you specify a command to use on hits.  It will run the command for each file `find` finds, and put the name of the file in `{}`.  You end the sequence of commands by specifying `\;`.

So to `echo` all the files, do this:

```
$ find . -type f -iname submit.pdf -exec echo Found file {} \;
```

To copy them one by one:

```
$ find . -type f -iname submit.pdf -exec cp {} /destination/folder \;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming that "submit.pdf" is the name of the file you want to find, and not a folder.

Comment: I believe the poster's problem wasn't finding/copying the files, so much as that he's copying multiple files with the same name (`submit.pdf`) into a single directory…?

Comment: BRPocock: You're right, but I'll leave this here as a general "how to use find" anyway. :)